# Error while deploying locally - Azure IOT remote monitoring suite

Tags: powershell, azure, iot, azure-powershell, azure-iot-hub

Team,

We are trying out this IOT remote monitoring suite from github. We are trying to first deploy that locally instead of Azure and hence we have followed the document mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/blob/master/Docs/local-deployment.md

Also, we have followed the pre-requisites over here https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/blob/master/Docs/dev-setup.md

We then come over to my developer command prompt (running as admin) but we end up having error:

> Get-AzureEnvironment : The 'Get-AzureEnvironment' command was found in
>   the module 'Azure', but the module could not be loaded. For more
>   information, r 'Import-Module Azure'. At
>   C:\Users\swagh\Downloads\azure-iot-remote-monitoring-master\azure-iot-re
>   -monitoring-master\Common\Deployment\PrepareIoTSample.ps1:14 char:14
>   +         if ((Get-AzureEnvironment AzureCloud) -eq $null)
>   +              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureEnvironment:String)    , CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
>
> Get-AzureRMEnvironment : The 'Get-AzureRMEnvironment' command was
>   found in module 'AzureRM', but the module could not be loaded. For
>   more information, run 'Import-Module AzureRM'.

The modules has been imported successfully but not sure why it fails while building the soln locally. Tried setting the execution policy to bypass, unrestricted. Also scoped to the current user but its not helping.

We have run out of ideas. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please run this command to show azure powershell version `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, it seems you have not install Azure PowerShell correctly.

We can install download Azure PowerShell [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.2.0-July2017/azure-powershell.4.2.0.msi). After download `azure-powershell.4.2.0.msi` completed, run as administrator.

We can find latest version of Azure powershell [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

[image]

We can run this command in Azure PowerShell version 4.2.0:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.  I shall try this one out and get back to you

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have attached the screenshot. Can you please take a further look and advise?

Comment: @SandeepWagh How about download this msi file, and install it?  download it from here https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.2.0-July2017/azure-powershell.4.2.0.msi

Comment: You can copy this link to you browse and download it. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.2.0-July2017/azure-powershell.4.2.0.msi

Comment: I downloaded the msi file and installed it...and the version now shows the same as you first shown in your screenshot. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: @SandeepWagh Please try to restart your laptop, and run this command again.

Comment: @SandeepWagh `Tried setting the execution policy to bypass, unrestricted.`   Do you mean you have try this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and it does not work for you?

Comment: that's right..it does not allow me to set any policy.

Comment: @SandeepWagh have no permission to set it?

Comment: @SandeepWagh Can we run powershell as administrator? maybe we can use administrator account to run this command.

Comment: @SandeepWagh Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I tried to run the powershell as admin too. But the same errror. Last thing i am trying to do is to uninstall everything and reload the Azure RM and check.

Comment: Sorry Jason, I am still getting the same error. In fact while trying to import the Azure Rm i get thisImport-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\4.2.1\AzureRM.psm1 cannot be
its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Poli
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module AzureRM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: @SandeepWagh please wait few mins, let me do some checking, I will give you update later:)

Comment: @SandeepWagh could you please run this command and show the return to me?  command is `$PSVersionTable`  and this command `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Answer (score 0):

[Azure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAq92.png)

The screenshot for the above error.

Comment: Please try to download `azure-powershell.4.2.0.msi` file, and install it via UI.

Comment: Sorry..Which UI are you talking about?

Comment: Download the file, then install it, I add the link in my answer,please check it. File name is azure-power shell-4.2.0. You can copy that link to you browse then download it

Comment: Download this file and double click it to install Azure power shell

Comment: I downloaded the msi file and installed it...and the version now shows the same as you first shown in your screenshot. But I am getting the same error

Comment: Do you mean you have install powershell msi, and now powershell can show the right version?